# How I can use Integrated Security in a ASP.NET Application that runs on a IIS7 Webserver?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, iis-7, connection-string

Hi I want to connect with a sql server 2012 in asp.net and my problem is if i test my application on my localhost then I get a connection but if i test it on the webserver (iis7) then I don't can connect to the database.

I et this message:

```
Error by login with user '[DOMAIN]\[SERVER]$'.
```

the application try to connect with machine Oo?

Here my code:

```
protected void btn_OpenDataBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionstring = "Server=[ip];Database=DB_CM0;Integrated Security=true";

                DataBaseManager db = new DataBaseManager();
                string isconnection = db.ConnectionTest(connectionstring);

                Response.Write(isconnection);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }

        }

public string ConnectionTest(string connectionstring) 
        {
            using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    return "Verbindung ist vorhanden";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { 
                    return ex.Message;
                }
            }

        }
```

My Situation:

We have a sql server 2012 and we use not a database user, we use windows authentication...

for this i want to use Integrated Security :/